# Is it possible to dynamically send new data to a specific user in my web application via WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Currently I have a C# application and a ASP.NET Web Application. I used WCF to pass data directly from the ASP.NET Web Application to the C# application. However, the ASP.NET Web Application relies on AJAX Timers (Polling) to dynamically updates pages with new data from a database. The database is constantly being updated.

Is it possible to have the C# application pass data dynamically to the ASP.NET web application via WCF and eliminate the need for timers and polling? The C# application would need to be able to check if a certain user is connected, send data to that user.

I am not sure if this is feasible, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to check.

Comment: Check https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/ Your best friend. Check jabbr.net which is built based on SignalR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know three alternatives:

Probably the feature will be WebSockets, but right now they have not been standarized, so meanwhile, I think SignalR is the best bet

- Use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), [SignalR Docs](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki)
- WebSockets (they are used in StackOverflow)

  - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/
  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket
- Comet:

  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: I have looked at WebSockets and Comet before. I am trying to understand how I would implement this. If I have user A and user B connected and they are on random web pages within my ASP.NET Web application. If my C# application receives data that is suppose to be for user A, where/how would I receive this data within the Web Application and then give it to user A? I see that the web sockets provide a message received callback...

Comment: I would suggest you to check SignalR first, it is really simple to implement

Comment: There's also dual instancing in WCF (eg wsdualhttpbinding). I've used these before, but you might have problems with it being an asp.net hosted service.

Comment: Signalr will also use websockets if they're available.

Comment: @SimonHalsey the WCF service is self-hosted in my C# application.

Comment: Signalr is your best best. The dual interfaces work great app-to-app, but to a web page it would get messy

Comment: I have looked into SignalR, I will be using it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ).

Using the MSMQ would spare you from explicitly polling for any new messages. Instead a handle method would become active as soon a a new message arrives.

WCF can easiliy be configured to use MSMQ as the underlying transport medium.

Some articles/ tutorials to get you started:

- MSDN: [MSMQ and WCF: Getting Started](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/motleyqueue/archive/2009/05/31/msmq-and-wcf-getting-started.aspx)
- [Message Queuing to Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751490)
- A more compley scenario with secured communation: [Creating a WCF Service with MSMQ Communication and Certificate
  Security](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326909/Creating-a-WCF-Service-with-MSMQ-Communication-and) (Code Project)
- [Leveraging MSMQ in ASP.NET Applications](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/internet/article.php/c19563/Leveraging-MSMQ-in-ASPNET-Applications.htm)

Comment: MSMQ isn't really appropriate to the problem. It gives you reliable messaging, rather than async signalling. Not that message queues aren't useful in some instances though.

Comment: @SimonHalsey: MSMQ gives you both sync and async methods to work with the queue. One of its main intentions is to decouple sender and receiver, which wouldn't work if the queues worked only synchronously. Instead working this the queues is independent even from the online/ offline state of the other endpoint and highly configurable. Given an appropriate software architecture, MSMQ is very well suited for this task.

Comment: Without a doubt, everything you say is true but in this case the same effect can be achieved without deploying a heavyweight solution like queuing.